# Syntax error for DIV in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, syntax-error, code-behind

I am trying to impliment below :

```
eventListingPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style="overflow :auto; width:200px;  height:200px">"));
```

but i am getting an error :

> ") expected"

with the red underline for keywords overflow ,auto,200px, 200px in the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not escaping your `"`

```
eventListingPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style=\"overflow :auto; width:200px;  height:200px\">"));
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
eventListingPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style=\"overflow :auto; width:200px;  height:200px\"></div>"));
```

Comment: Actualy i was not closing the div :-)  anyway +1